# Javascript unlimited category depth tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, underscore.js

I am trying to generate a tree of flat array , placing sub categories next to the parent category and having hard doing same.

```js
var categories = [
  {
    name: 'Javascript'
  },
  {
    name: 'jQuery',
    parent: 'Javascript'
  },
  {
    name: 'AngularUi',
    parent: 'Angular'
  },
  {
    name: 'Angular',
    parent: 'Javascript'
  },
  {
    name: 'D3',
    parent: 'Javascript'
  }
];

var tree = [];

function getChilds(array,identifier){
    return _.filter(array,function(val){
        return val.parent == identifier
    });
}

function createTree(array){
    for(var x=0;x<_.size(array);x++){
      tree.push(array[x].name);
      var childs = getChilds(array,array[x].name);
        if(_.size(childs) > 0){
          createTree(childs);
        }else{
          $('div').append(JSON.stringify(tree));
        }
    }
}

createTree(categories);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Expected Output

```
['Javascript','Jquery','Angular','AngularUi','D3']
```

This is what i have tried so far, and using underscore for little help. Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: Still you haven't clarified about the result

Comment: I have added expected output , that should be an array ['Javascript','Jquery','Angular','AngularUi','D3']

Comment: `tree.push(array[x].name);` is created thats array, for what you get childs?

Comment: @Waki didn't get, i am trying to place every child next to it's parent and they can be unlimited

Comment: What do you mean "next to it's parent"? What if a node has multiple children, all of which have their own children? It seems as though you expect the children to be sorted, followed immediately by their own children.

Comment: @ssube Yes absolutely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to do this (the result you have described is not a tree at all), but the following will provide the result you are describing:

```js
function addChildren(source, identifier, dest) {
  source.filter(function(val) {
    return val.parent == identifier;
  }).forEach(function(val) {
    dest.push(val.name);
    addChildren(source, val.name, dest);
  });
}

function buildTree(source) {
  var dest = [];
  addChildren(source, undefined, dest);
  return dest;
}

var categories = [{
  name: 'Javascript'
}, {
  name: 'jQuery',
  parent: 'Javascript'
}, {
  name: 'AngularUi',
  parent: 'Angular'
}, {
  name: 'Angular',
  parent: 'Javascript'
}, {
  name: 'D3',
  parent: 'Javascript'
}];


var tree = buildTree(categories);
```

Note that the approach above using `filter` is an O(N<sup>2</sup>) operation (it's very inefficient).

You can change it into an O(N) operation by indexing the source arrray first using [`_.groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

```js
function addChildren(index, identifier, dest) {
    (index[identifier] || []).forEach(function (val) {
        dest.push(val.name);
        addChildren(index, val.name, dest);
    });
}

function buildTree(source) {
    var dest = [];
    addChildren(_.groupBy(source, 'parent'), undefined, dest);
    return dest;
}

var categories = [{
    name: 'Javascript'
}, {
    name: 'jQuery',
    parent: 'Javascript'
}, {
    name: 'AngularUi',
    parent: 'Angular'
}, {
    name: 'Angular',
    parent: 'Javascript'
}, {
    name: 'D3',
    parent: 'Javascript'
}];

var tree = buildTree(categories);
console.log(tree);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: BRAVO , seems to be working great , i have some complex hooks system where i want to execute them one after the other depending upon their parent. That example would have been so complex to publish here, that is why i used this category example. THANKS A TON